# Why can't I iterate over a Counter in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is that when I try to do the below, I get the `need more than 1 value to unpack`?

```
for key,value in countstr:
    print key,value


for key,value in countstr:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

However this works just fine:

```
for key,value in countstr.most_common():
    print key,value
```

I don't understand, aren't `countstr` and `countstr.most_common()` equivalent?

EDIT:
Thanks for the below answers, then I guess what I don't understand is: If `countstr` is a mapping what is `countstr.most_common()`? -- I'm really new to Python, sorry if I am missing something simple here.

Comment: `countstr.most_common()` is a list of key-value pairs, sorted in descending order of value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they're not.  Iterating over a mapping (be it a `collections.Counter` or a `dict` or ...) iterates only over the mapping's keys.

And there's another difference:  iterating over the keys of a `Counter` delivers them in no defined order.  The order returned by `most_common()` is defined (sorted in reverse order of value).

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't equivalent.  `countstr` is a `Counter` which is a dictionary subclass.  Iterating over it yields 1 key at a time.  `countstr.most_common()` is a list which contains 2-tuples (ordered key-value pairs).

Answer (score 1):

A countstr is a Counter which is a subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where `elements` are stored as `dictionary keys` and their `counts` are stored as `dictionary values`.

```
>>> c = Counter(a=4, b=2, c=0, d=-2)
>>> list(c.elements())
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate the counter values/keys directly but you can copy them into a list and iterate the list.

```
s = ["bcdef", "abcdefg", "bcde", "bcdef"]

import collections
counter=collections.Counter(s)

vals = list(counter.values())
keys = list(counter.keys())

vals[0]
keys[0]
```

Output:

```
 2
'bcdef'
```